# The Oracle's IQ Test

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, progressive-matrix, humor

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sub>

---

I was feeling pretty confident and secure about my intellect so I decided to ask the Oracle for her opinion. I sent her a message and she responded immediately with three messages:

[image]

What is this? An IQ test? I just wanna know how smart I am.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are...

> ...a **Genius**!

Because...

> stab star sea
> cab car key
> jab jar ("jee")
>
> tear toes tea
> beer Bose bee
> near nose ("nee")
>
> bold bat bus
> cold cat cuss
> old at ("us")
>
>  ...gives us:
>
>  "jee" + "nee" + "us" = genius.

Comment: Perfect answer. You must be one too!

Comment: What is the merhod to derive the "word" for the question marks?

Comment: @KCWong I believe the start of the syllable is the start of the words in its row, the end that of those in its column. Although I confess I'm a bit perplexed by "old at us"- that doesn't seem to fit my stated rule regarding the start of the syllable.

Comment: The method to go from the emoji to word is also perplexing. 3rd image middle row you can easily go "Freeze" "Feline" "Fuck".

Comment: @LieutenantZipp "old at us" means the initial consonant (the "onset", in linguistics term) is empty. The columns define the "rhymes", the rows define the "onsets".

Comment: @KCWong: yes, there are lots of other words that fit for lots of the emoji. You can bet "stab" isn't the first word I thought of for the fencer! But it's kind of like a crossword puzzle...the wrong words might fit the emoji, but the end up not making sense in the bigger pattern.

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of emoji grid puzzle?